# Bash pid returns nothing at all

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kill

I was learning bash with a book called learning the bash shell. All was well until I came across the `kill` command. I created a little script called `loop`, then ran it using `loop &`. When I use `kill %loop`, then use `ps -e | grep loop`, the process is still there. So did I fail to kill it? Do I have to use `kill -9`?  Also,`pidof` seemed to not work at all when I use `pidof loop`. It returns nothing at all.

I am using Ubuntu and bash. Although I think the script shouldn't matter, here it is just in case:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Just a script
while true; do
    sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell scripts don't run as the name of the script. They run as the name of the shell you specify in the shebang. In your case, that's `/bin/bash`. If you'd done `pidof bash` you'd have gotten the pid of your script (along with all the other bash scripts running at the time).

That being said, you can't kill scripts by their name, as you're trying with `kill %loop`. Kill only accepts pids. If you're using the `%` notation, then that refers to the internal job number assigned by the shell. e.g, using your loop script as an example:

```
$ ./loop &  <-- first run of loop script
[1] 8077    <--- job #1, running as pid 8077
$ ./loop &  <--- second run of loop script
[2] 8079    <-- job #2, running as pid 8079
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ./loop &
[2]+  Running                 ./loop &
$ kill %2
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 ./loop &
[2]+  Terminated              ./loop    <-- note, showing 'terminated' now
$ kill -9 8077
$ jobs
[1]+  Killed                  ./loop
$ jobs
$
```

Comment: Great answer.  You can also run `pidof -x loop` to get the pid of the process by the script name.

Comment: the bash builtin `kill` absolutely does accept job names, so long as they're not ambiguous.

Comment: doesn't on the bash I'm using: `kill %loop` -> `bash: kill: %loop no such job`, on `GNU bash, version 3.00.15(1)-release (i386-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @evilotto yeah,that's why when i have several loop running as background jobs  can't use kill %loop :P

Comment: @MansoorSiddiqui pidof -x loop worked like a charm.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarcB: try `kill %./loop` - the string has to match the command you used exactly (or a prefix therof, like `kill %./`)